# Logical addressing calculation

Tags: operating-system

There are 8 Logical address pages from 0 to 7

Total size of the frame is 1024 bytes

CPU accesses the next line of code : 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0

first 4 bits are the opcode

size of the word 32 bits.

I am not getting how to calculate the logical page number and page offset from the given data..can anyone help me how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe more information is needed, maybe if we know what the instruction actually do, we might be able to see if it reference a memory location. Then answering it would be possilbe